# Join Keys from 2 nodes in a single return value in Neo4j 3.2.15 and cypher-3.1

Tags: join, neo4j, return, cypher-3.1

I'm trying to get a "Friend Recommendation" query. The nodes have the next sequence
`(Node) - [FRIEND] - (Node) - [INFO] - (P_info)`
where every node have a `INFO`relation with a `P_info` node asociated. I can get a list of recommended friends of a Node but i need to include the `P_info` keys into recommended friends keys to return all together.

This is my query at the moment:

```
match (person:Account{_id:"185860469"})
match (person)-[:FRIEND]-()-[:FRIEND]-(potentialFriend)
where not (person)-[:FRIEND]-(potentialFriend)
match (potentialFriend)-[:INFO]-(information:P_info)
with person,potentialFriend, COUNT(*) AS friendsInCommon,information
where friendsInCommon > 5
return {user:person,recommend:collect(potentialFriend)},{info:information}
```

but the information of "info" is not asociated with "potentialFriend" at the response.
I want to do something like this:
`return {user:person,collect(potentialFriend,information)}` but i don't know if it's possible, cypher says:

> Too many parameters for function 'collect'

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it, just adding an additional `WITH`.I leave the answer in case someone helps

```
WITH person,{friend_id:potentialFriend._id,friend_name:information.name} AS Recommended_friend
RETURN person._id,collect(Recommended_friend)
```

this will return an unique response with person id and an array with all the recommended friends for him.